# `getstr` in ncurses egg (Chicken Scheme)

Tags: scheme, ncurses, chicken-scheme

I'm trying to figure how to use the function `getstr` of [this egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/ncurses) (and consequently of `mvgetstr`, `mvwgetstr`, etc...).
For example:

```
(require-extension ncurses)

(let ((stdscr (initscr)) (str (make-string 10)))
  (getstr str)
  (addstr str)
  (getch))
```

`csi` tells me

> Error: bad argument type - not a pointer: "          "

So i tried with this:

```
(require-extension ncurses)

(let ((stdscr (initscr)) (str (make-string 10)))
  (begin      
  (getstr (object->pointer str))
   (addstr str)
   (getch))))
```

This time `csi` give me another error:

> Error: bad argument type - not a string: [panic] Detected corrupted data in stack - execution terminated

I think the problem is about the encoding of the string (a function thinks is ascii and another utf-8). I've no experience with pointer in scheme, I simply would know the best idiot-proof way to get a string with this egg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I think this is a bug of the ncurses egg. [Here](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/chicken-janitors/2010-01/msg00028.html) they say this was a bug and it has been correct but I have the same problem with the last version.

However these functions were not really scheme-like and it's simple to redefine these functions using `getch` (which works correctly).
For example:

```
(define (mvgetstr x y)
  (move y x)
  (let loop ((str ""))
    (let ((ch (getch)))
      (if (eq? (char->integer ch ) 10) ;10 is the ENTER KEY code
      str
      (loop (string-append str (string ch)))))))
```

Edit: another user suggested a way to use this function and similar:

```
(use ncurses lolevel data-structures)

(define (get-string max)
  (let ((buffer (make-string max #\null)))
    (getnstr (make-locative buffer) max)
    (string-translate buffer #\null)))

(let ((stdscr (initscr))
      (str (get-string 10)))
  (addstr str)
  (getch)
  (write str))
```

Comment: yeah, it's unfortunate how low-level the ncurses egg is :(  There's an alternative egg for dealing with curses called [mojo](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/mojo), but it isn't very complete and hasn't been worked on in a long time. You might find it interestng though!

Comment: I know it but it didn't provided what I wanted, however I found a workaround to use `mvgetstr` and similar, I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for version 5 of Chicken Scheme:

```
(import ncurses
     (chicken locative)
     (chicken string))

(let ((stdscr (initscr)) (str (make-string 10)))
    (getstr (make-locative str))
    (addstr (string-translate str #\null))
    (getch)
    (endwin))
```